# Difference in blowfish encryption between Perl and Java

Tags: java, perl, encryption, blowfish

We´re writing and application in both Java and Perl storing encrypted CBC Blowfish in the same database. Both will be encrypting and decrypting, so they need to be able to get the plain text that the other encrypted.

a) I went to some online tools to encrypt some text with CBC and IV vector. One such site [is this](http://sladex.org/blowfish.js/)
plaintext  HELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOU
key 1234567890
since the site does not allow to enter the IV vector we assumed it would be zeroed which turned out to be right:

*ciphertext*
P4mtWDzIIc2x/Taqc9T46A3T0aTCelmANBRf6RgEzSF29DLdMRiEhck98jac04+Tg0q7HpLalow0J6nZNUW+HWtRvYmLnt92UuIZ1ckaBEa9TSdR2YP9rQ==

b) The following Java code does the encryption:

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;  
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;  

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;

public class simple {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String Key = "1234567890";
   byte[] KeyData = Key.getBytes(); 
   String IV    = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

   try { 
     SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(KeyData, "Blowfish");
     // modo CBC
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
     try {
       try {    
         IvParameterSpec IVparam = new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes());                     
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KS,IVparam);
       } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {System.out.println(e);};  
     } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {System.out.println(e);};  

    // get the text to encrypt
    String inputText = "HELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOU";

    // encrypt message
    try {
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(inputText.getBytes());
      Base64 b64 = new Base64();
      System.out.println("Java Ciphertext\n" + b64.encodeAsString(encrypted));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    catch (BadPaddingException e) {System.out.println(e);}  
   }  
   catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {}
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
 }   

}
```

The output is:
*Java Ciphertext*
P4mtWDzIIc2x/Taqc9T46A3T0aTCelmANBRf6RgEzSF29DLdMRiEhck98jac04+Tg0q7HpLalow0J6nZNUW+HWtRvYmLnt92UuIZ1ckaBEaLkpDfHZfp8g==

As you can see both outputs are "almost" the same (Maybe due to padding but that's no relevant at the moment. It´s strange however since the plaintext is intentionally 80 caracters to avoid padding)

c) We wrote this small Perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Crypt::Blowfish;
use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::CBC;

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key => "1234567890\0\0\0\0\0\0", -cipher => "Blowfish", -iv => "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", -literal_key => 1, -header => "none", -keysize => 16);
my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt("HELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOU");

print "Perl Base64: ",encode_base64($ciphertext),"\n"; 
print "Descrifrado: ", $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

But this program produce the following:
*Perl Base64:*   AW0AYJfIp1Lg5L+zTM0nZj07U6ETlxxIg3CKiZItg8wkA1Jqx79ZckzWfYwzN26ZPyCDnlfh0b37
0ZK61ng8MaMc9RFgtuXTeYLBOJC7LGYCHlMddmPwUQ==
*Descrifrado:* HELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOUHELLOYOU

Which is not the same as the Java program (which is consistent with the online tools) although it can get the plain text correctly

So maybe we are not prompting the same parameters in the object creation. In particular:

```
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key => "1234567890\0\0\0\0\0\0", -cipher => "Blowfish", -iv => "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", -literal_key => 1, -header => "none", -keysize => 16);
```

After inspecting the code my only guess is that Java and Perl use different key size, so my question is

¿What key size does Java use? After browsing the source code for *SecretKeySpec* [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec-source.html) we could not determine such size so 128 bits was assumed, hence the 16 size (16 x 8 = 128) and the \0 padding of the key in the Perl code.

Of course, If you can spot something else wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tip: Using `encode_base64($ciphertext, '')` instead of `encode_base64($ciphertext)` prevents line feeds from being added in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you use

```
String Key = "1234567890";
```

In Perl, you use

```
my $key = "1234567890\0\0\0\0\0\0";
```

If you actually used the same key, you'd get the same result.

```
my $key = "1234567890";

-literal_key => 1, -key => $key, -keysize => length($key)
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I got confused about the -keysize parameter [here](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC-2.33/CBC.pm):  
 -keysize        Force the cipher keysize to the indicated number of bytes.

Comment: Blowfish expects a wide range of keys sizes (8..56) since it really expects a passphrase. Crypt::CBC expects that each algorithm always wants a key of the same size, so it asks the algorithm what size it wants in order to validate the key provided. The backend, Crypt::Blowfish, needs to tells Crypt::CBC something, so it says it expects a key of size 0. You must override Crypt::CBC's check by saying a `-keysize` of the length you provided is expected. Crypt::Blowfish still validates the size of the key.